# Ruby code inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby form that saves a city id value:

```
= select_tag 'building[city_id]',
options_for_select(cities.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]})
```

I'm saving that id using Javascript:

```
var city_id = $('#building_city_id').val();
```

My issue is that I also need a Javascript variable for a city name, which I can get using Ruby like this: `City.find(@building.city.id).name`.
I tried this code, but it doesn't wotk:

```
var city_name = #{City.find(city_id).name};
```

Where is my mistake? (I'm very new to Ruby)

Comment: You can't call Ruby from JavaScript being run inside the browser. Are you trying to run Ruby inside ERB or a template processor inside Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the Rails server parses the `html.erb` view before `city_id` is defined.

`city_id` is a Javascript variable defined by the client browser *after* receiving the view which contains `var city_name = #{City.find(city_id).name};`.

You could do an Ajax call that would execute `City.find(city_id).name` on the server and fill `var city_name` with the response. Once you know the user has filled an `input` with some text you can use (i.e. city_id), you can make a call like so (put this either in the view or in a separate js file):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/your_ajax_endpoint",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {'city_id': city_id},
  success: function(data) {
    var city_name = data;
  },
  error: function(data) {
    // Error handling
  }
});
```

The endpoint in your controller would look like this:

```
def my_ajax_endpoint
    city_name = City.find(city_id).name
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: city_name.to_json }
    end
end
```

Comment: Any ideas how do I get a city name while user is filling a form? I need a city name for showing a building on google maps. Where do I do that Ajax call?

Comment: @Nadiya With ajax. I've edited my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data using javascript. Here is an example taken from [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?autoplay=true).

*products/index.html.erb*

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "products", data: {products: Product.limit(10)} do %>
  Loading products...
<% end %>
```

*app/assets/javascripts/products.js.coffee*

```
jQuery ->
  alert $('#products').data('products')
```

Or you can use the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon).